# Activity stucked after returning from Activity that changed Night Mode

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm facing a weird problem in which my Activity gets stuck with a black screen and the last callback from the lifecycle is the `onStop()`.

The flow is:

1. MainActivity open an AnotherActivity
2. AnotherActivity change the app's night mode (the important part is force the app to change from night to light or vice-versa)
3. Finish AnotherActivity. After this the app should resume MainActivity

After step 3 the bug appears.

Among all the APIs that I've tested, after step 3:

- From API 16 to API 22: The MainActivity only shows a black screen;
- From API 16 to API 28: The last lifecycle call made by MainActivity is the `onStop()`.

Here is the code of both Activities that I'm using.
The full project is available in [my GitHub Repository](https://github.com/GustavoAraujoLetras/TestingIssue3759).

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.gustavogoma.android.test.testingissue3759

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        if (shouldOpenAnotherActivity) {
            shouldOpenAnotherActivity = false

            startActivity(Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestart")
        super.onRestart()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG,  "onStop")
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName

        private var shouldOpenAnotherActivity = true
    }
}
```

**AnotherActivity.kt**

```
package com.gustavogoma.android.test.testingissue3759

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_another.*

class AnotherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another)



        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
            {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)

                finish()
            },
            5000
        )
    }
}
```

**MainActivity logcat (Android 16):**

```
11-26 17:03:45.806 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onCreate
11-26 17:03:46.098 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onStart
11-26 17:03:46.101 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onResume
11-26 17:03:46.114 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onPause
11-26 17:03:46.344 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onStop
11-26 17:03:51.310 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onRestart
11-26 17:03:51.311 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onStart
11-26 17:03:51.312 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onResume
11-26 17:03:51.354 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onPause
11-26 17:03:51.355 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onStop
11-26 17:03:51.355 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onDestroy
11-26 17:03:51.357 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onCreate
11-26 17:03:51.383 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onStart
11-26 17:03:51.383 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onResume
11-26 17:03:51.392 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onPause
11-26 17:03:51.393 2051-2051 I/MainActivity: onStop
```

Comment: I managed to reproduce it locally, but I got no idea on how to fix it :/. And as a heads up, sometimes the last lifecycle printed was `onPause`. That's a very strange behavior from Android =/